# Testing Express and Mongoose with Mocha

Tags: node.js, testing, express, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm trying to test my REST API endpoint handlers using Mocha and Chai, the application was built using Express and Mongoose. My handlers are mostly of the form:

```
var handler = function (req, res, next) {
    // Process the request, prepare the variables

    // Call a Mongoose function
    Model.operation({'search': 'items'}, function(err, results) {
        // Process the results, send call next(err) if necessary

        // Return the object or objects
        return res.send(results)
    }
}
```

For example:

```
auth.getUser = function (req, res, next) {
    // Find the requested user
    User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, user) {
        // If there is an error, cascade down
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        // If the user was not found, return 404
        else if (!user) {
            return res.status(404).send('The user could not be found');
        }
        // If the user was found
        else {
            // Remove the password
            user = user.toObject();
            delete user.password;

            // If the user is not the authenticated user, remove the email
            if (!(req.isAuthenticated() && (req.user.username === user.username))) {
                delete user.email;
            }

            // Return the user
            return res.send(user);
        }
    });
};
```

The problem with this is that the function returns as it calls the Mongoose method and test cases like this:

```
it('Should create a user', function () {
    auth.createUser(request, response);

    var data = JSON.parse(response._getData());
    data.username.should.equal('some_user');
});
```

never pass as the function is returning before doing anything. Mongoose is mocked using Mockgoose and the request and response objects are mocked with Express-Mocks-HTTP.

While using superagent and other request libraries is fairly common, I would prefer to test the functions in isolation, instead of testing the whole framework.

Is there a way to make the test wait before evaluating the should statements without changing the code I'm testing to return promises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, express-mocks-http was abandoned a while ago and the new code is under node-mocks-http. Using this new library it is possible to do what I was asking for using events. It's not documented but looking at the code you can figure it out.

When creating the response object you have to pass the EventEmitter object:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var response = NodeMocks.createResponse({eventEmitter: EventEmitter});
```

Then, on the test, you add a listener to the event 'end' or 'send' as both of them are triggered when the call to res.send. 'end' covers more than 'send', in case you have calls other than res.send (for example, res.status(404).end().

The test would look something like this:

```
it('Should return the user after creation', function (done) {
    auth.createUser(request, response);

    response.on('send', function () {
        var data = response._getData();

        data.username.should.equal('someone');
        data.email.should.equal('asdf2@asdf.com');

        done();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an asynchronous version of the test, by providing a function with a `done` argument to `it`.

For more details refer to http://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code.

Since you don't want to modify your code, one way to do that could be by using `setTimeout` in the test to wait before to call done.

I would try something like this:

```
it('Should create a user', function (done) {
    auth.createUser(request, response);

    setTimeout(function(){
        var data = JSON.parse(response._getData());
        data.username.should.equal('some_user');

        done(); 
     }, 1000); // waiting one second to perform the test
});
```

(*There might be better way*)

Comment: I think a better option here would be to replace the res.send function with a fake that calls done, thanks for the inspiration. In any case, I found a way of doing it using node-mocks-http instead of express-mocks-http. I'm writing the answer.

Comment: give a look to https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest and https://github.com/pgte/nock. (i used the former to test a simple rest api server)

Comment: They look good, especially nock. The problem with supertest is that it is for mocking the HTTP request and not the request object, the tests would go through all the node/express stack. I prefer the unit test to call specific functions to see if they work on their own. Nock will be useful for functions that call outside, although right now I have only a couple of those.